# C++-CLI Button Arrays to C# Button Arrays in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

I am designing an application in C# Winforms (for the first time). I've designed several applications in C++ in the past, and am having difficulty converting some of my C++-CLI functions to C#.

I have 5 buttons along a side bar that toggles the visibility of the button's corresponding panel per button click. In order to do this, I set the visibility of all other panels to false. In order to achieve this in C++-CLI, I've done the following:

```
private: System::Void panels_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    System::Windows::Forms::Button ^ currentbutton = (System::Windows::Forms::Button ^) sender;
    array < Panel ^ > ^ objects = { panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6};
    array < Button ^ > ^ buttons = { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (buttons[i]->Equals(currentbutton)) {
            objects[i]->Visible = true;
        }
        else objects[i]->Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is with the " array Panel ^" portion, as I can not find an equivalent in C#. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: var objects = new Panel[] { panel1, panel2, panel3 };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are declared in C# using `TypeName[]`.

```
Panel[] objects = { panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6 };
Button[] buttons = { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6 };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cast the `Controls` collection to a `List<Control>`, and then access the control name for comparison. The `Cast<T>()` method is a linq extension method, so you'll have to add `using System.Linq;` to your namespace:

```
private void panels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> panelNames = new List<string>
    {"panel1", "panel2", "panel3", "panel4", "panel5", "panel6"};

    List<string> buttonNames = new List<string>
    {"button1", "button2", "button3", "button4", "button5", "button6"};

    List<Control> panels = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Where(ctrl => panelNames.Contains(ctrl.Name)).ToList();

    List<Control> buttons = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Where(ctrl => buttonNames.Contains(ctrl.Name)).ToList();

    Button thisButton = sender as Button;

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < panels.Count) panels[i].Visible = buttons[i] == thisButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-voter, please let me know how this answer can be improved.